# How to add a border color to an OutlineButton

Tags: flutter, border, flutter-layout

How can I add a border color to an OutlineButton? I tried setting a `highlightedBorderColor`, but it is not working. How can I solve this issue?

This is my code:

```
 OutlineButton(
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
   onPressed:(){},child: Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
   child: Text("add to cart",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 20),),
    ),highlightedBorderColor: Colors.red,
 ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your code:

```
borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.red),
```

This should change the border color of your button to red

Answer (score 2):

Take a try with it:

```
      OutlineButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink, width: 1),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Text(
              "add to cart",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        )
```